# Is there a way to have specific settings activated when using the term feature?

Tags: vimrc, terminal

I often have neovim in a horizontal split mode with two buffers. The top buffer is the text file that I'm editing, and the bottom buffer is running a terminal using the `term` feature. I typically use line number and relative line numbering in my buffer with code, but would like to turn that off in my buffer with the term. Is there a way to specify that buffers that are activated as `term`s automatically `set nornu` and `set nonu`?

Comment: Weird, I’m pretty sure in vim when I do `:terminal` there are no line numbers (I have both kinds set globally as well).

Comment: Maybe it's just a neovim thing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can open the terminal (or create a map) with

```
:exe 'ter'|se nornu nonu
```

Or create an auto-command in `.vimrc`:

```
autocmd TerminalOpen * set nonu nornu
```

Comment: In neovim, the corresponding autocmd event is `TermOpen`